# Angular 2 Async requires click on route to render data

Tags: angular

I have encountered a weird issue in my app where I'm querying async data and it comes back fine, but it isn't rendered in the view unless I click on the route again. Could anyone please tell me if this can be fixed or is a bug?

Here is my code:

```
constructor( private _firebase: FirebaseService ) { }   
ngOnInit() { 
    //observable
    this.ideaData = this._firebase.GetObjectAtPath('stages/' + this.stage + '/' + this.ideaId);
}
```

View:

```
{{ (ideaData | async)?.title }}
```

Comment: I think I've narrowed this down to the fact the async call is outside the Zone and it doesn't update the view when it completes. This baffles me as zone monkey patches all Http requests and makes them accesible inside Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment in your code, `this.ideaData` actually gets assigned an observable that you can subscribe to.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._firebase
    .GetObjectAtPath('stages/' + this.stage + '/' + this.ideaId)
    .subscribe(result => this.ideaData = result, err => console.log(err));
}
```

More on observables/subscriptions here: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/subscribe.md

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. I did try that as well, but regardless of how I'm consuming the data from the observable, it required an extra click on the route to render the data

Comment: Gotcha. I just looked up the [async pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#!#async-pipe) and I see what you're saying now.